# IE6 debug javascript

Tags: javascript, debugging, internet-explorer-6

I know it has been asked, but this is strange in IE6 (winxp).

JS code crashes at some point when:

```
var result = ....
if(result==200) <-- this is the reported error in IE6, something at line 62 char 5
```

and it works well in the latest Chrome, Firefox, etc.

Can you advise me on some tool for IE6 like the FireBug plugin (or something) to catch this?

Comment: So you are dealing with the [6.7% of the internet](http://www.ie6countdown.com/) that uses IE6? Sucks to be you.

Comment: @epascarello: It's actually less than 1% if you ignore China :)

Comment: If your application services large corporate environments, the percentage is much higher. but still, sucks to be you.

Comment: Fixing your problem won't help us kill off IE6 any sooner.

Comment: As of March 2013 [0.2% of total](http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_explorer.asp) (worldwide) internet users using internet explorer 6. I think nobody wants to spend effort to solve ancient problems like this anymore. IE6 died. RIP.

Comment: Can you boil your code down to a small code snippet that people can run?  Does your code ever do `delete result` or `delete x[y]` where `x == window && y == "result"`?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help you: https://getfirebug.com/firebuglite

It's a firebug clone in javascript, compatibile with IE6.

From the docs, on how to install it:

```
<!--  Include the following code at the top of the <head> of your page -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite.js"></script>
```

**edit**: Found out that debugging of javascript code is not supported. Anyway, as on the comments someone already said to you, look at this answer: [Debug JavaScript within IE6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/782689/debug-javascript-within-ie6).